# Start Firefox from Terminal on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, firefox

This is what I get when I try to start the executable:

```
Mac-Pro:MacOS george$ /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
  Reason: Incompatible library version: Security requires version 9.0.0 or later, but libsqlite3.dylib provides version 1.0.0
/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/run-mozilla.sh: line 131:  9870 Trace/BPT trap          "$prog" ${1+"$@"}
```

I also tried:

```
MacOS george$ open -a /Applications/Firefox

FSPathMakeRef(/Applications/Firefox) failed with error -43.
```

Is there a particular way to start the application from the command line?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The problem with your second attempt is that your path does not include the `.app` extenstion.

Try using either

```
open -a /Applications/Firefox.app
```

or

```
open /Applications/Firefox.app
```

Comment: Correct. I verified. The "old hit tab key to autocomplete trick" fixes that one for me.

Comment: `open -a Firefox` works just as well (unless you have multiple instances of the same program installed).

Answer (score 36):

These examples will open Firefox, open a specific website, or browse your user's home directory.

```
open -a firefox
open -a firefox -g http://news.google.com
open -a firefox -g $HOME
```

Comment: If anyone is wondering about `-g`, it opens an application on the background, so that it will either be placed behind the frontmost application or have no visible windows.

Comment: Much better than accepted answer, this one is easy to remember!
By analogy: `open -a 'Google Chrome'` or `open -a 'Brave Browser'`

Comment: Opening a specific website only seems to work if you use `-g`. Omitting `-g` will make firefox open but not go to the site.

Answer (score 13):

You want to run `/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin`

Comment: You can also use `/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox` without the `-bin`. To open a new tab in an existing window you can do `/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox --new-tab https://mail.google.com`. To see other options, use `/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox --help`

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old but maybe this answer could be helpful. You could also add

```
alias firefox="/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox"
```

to your *~/.zshrc* file. If you do not use *zshell* your preferred startup script will have a different name. When the next shell instance is started (or you executed `source ~/.zshrc`) you can open Firefox by typing

`firefox`